# Elements from list are overwritten in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I've been struggling for some days trying to figure out why my items from a python list are overwritten. Basically I have to implement a function that rotates 8 times a matrix.

```
def rotate_ring(matrix, offset):
dim = len(matrix[0])
print(dim)
last_element = matrix[offset][offset]
for j in range(1 + offset, dim - offset):
    matrix[offset][j-1] = matrix[offset][j]
matrix[offset][dim-1-offset] = matrix[1+offset][dim-1-offset]
for i in range(1 + offset, dim - offset):
    matrix[i-1][dim-1-offset] = matrix[i][dim-1-offset]
matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-1-offset] = matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-2-offset]
for j in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
    matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-j] = matrix[dim-1-offset][dim-j-1]
matrix[dim-1-offset][offset] = matrix[dim-2-offset][offset]
for i in range(1+offset, dim-offset):
    matrix[dim-i][offset] = matrix[dim-i-1][offset]
matrix[1+offset][offset] = last_element
return matrix


def rotate_matrix(matrix):
dim = len(matrix[0])
for offset in range(0, int(dim/2)):
    matrix = rotate_ring(matrix, offset)
return matrix
```

The functions above are the functions that rotate the matrix and they do because I checked them. After these functions were implemented, I implemented another function

```
def compass_filter(kernel):
#result = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype=np.float)
#result  = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype=np.float)
results = []
results.append(kernel)
for i in range(0,7):
    kernel = rotate_matrix(kernel) #rotate the kernel
    print(kernel)
    results.append(kernel) #appending to results
   
return results
```

that iterates, 8 times (because I always have 8 kernels) and append the kernels to a list. The problem that I have encountered is that the new rotated kernel is printed:

[image]

, but when I print the final list all I see is the last kernel printed 8 times. Does anybody what is the problem? I have also tried to do another list in the for loop just for the new element and then append it to the list that is outside the loop. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You are modifying `kernel` in-place, so the same object is placed in the final list each time.  So you end up seeing only the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the function compass filter as follows:

```
def compass_filter(kernel):
    results = [] 
    results.append(kernel)
    for i in range(7):
        kernel_ = np.array([rotate_matrix(kernel)])
        print(kernel_)
        results.append(kernel_)
   
   return results
```